# Location optimisation

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, location-allocation

I am trying to work out optimal locations of our devices for a given network with a set of placement rules. The main rule is that each device should be within range (i.e. 1000m) of one to two other device, but at most three devices (been within range of four or more is a waste). Then we have other rules like every dead-end should be within range of two devices if the dead-end has more than one destination within range.

Note: range is the same as driving distance.

I think my newness to GIS and its terms are letting me down, but I did stumbled on to `location-allocation` and `simulated annealing` but am unable to find a good examples I can hack to make it work with my rule set.
So, I’m here asking if I have the right rabbit holes with location-allocation and simulated annealing? Or is there a better way to do this when using PostGIS?
Are there any good examples of location-allocation using PostGIS?

Comment: Approximate solution. Pick any point and place points at 1k interval from it. Start weeding by finding worst offender and removing it. Repeat until no rule breaker found.

Comment: @FelixIP, I have tried this approach, but just removing rule breaker wasn't working. what we needed to do to fix a small test area by hand was to move some of the devices to the 500 - 900m mark. This put me on the path of simulated annealing but have been able to get a working test yet. Doing the fixes by hand will be unfeasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested my suggestion (100 m), by placing candidates at 50 m interval and removing points at intersections. I also removed ones closer than 25 m to each other:

[image]

I applied algorithm, breaking iteration when worst case become 2 neighbours within 100 m. Picture below shows number of neighbors within 100m walk:

[image]

It is not a big deal to move 3% of points with no neighbors down the road.
So it seems to work, unless I misunderstood your question.

BTW I am not sure how does  simulated annealing fit here, but I've tried it on a toy-sized set to solve traveling salesman problem and it failed real baaad.

Update - ArcGIS solution:

Important thing - flip roads that digitized towards dangling node. The way I do it: set dangles as destination nodes and compute distance for remaining nodes to nearest. Transfer travel distance to start and end of the initial network and balk flip conflicting edges. Split original edges at a equal length segments (50 m in my case). Mark nodes at intersection and ones closer than 25 m as non-candidates (field TYPE = 0 in nodes table).

```
import arcpy
import networkx as nx
links = "links"
nodes = "nodes"
G = nx.Graph() # create graph. fi,ti - node names, 
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(links,("fi","ti","LENGTH")) as cursor:
    for f,t,c in cursor: G.add_edge(f,t,weight=c)
nDict ={}
aSet = set() # dictionary of candidates
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(nodes,("OID@","TYPE")) as cursor:
    for fid, tp in cursor:
        nDict[fid]=tp
        if tp:aSet.add(fid)

while True: # weeding worst offendes one by one by computing no of neighbors - nMax
    nMax = 0
    for node in aSet:
        lengths = nx.single_source_dijkstra_path_length(G, node,101)
        nCur = len(lengths)-1
        for fid in lengths:
            if fid in aSet:continue
            nCur-=1
        if nCur<=nMax:continue
        nMax = nCur
        worst = node
    if nMax==2:break
    aSet.remove(worst)
    nDict[worst] = 0
    arcpy.AddMessage("%i with %i is worst" %(worst,nMax))

comment = 1 # transfer results to nodes table to show selected nodes
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(nodes,("OID@","ORIG_FID","COUNT")) as cursor:
    for fid, tp, cnt in cursor:
        if nDict[fid]==0:
            cursor.updateRow((fid,nDict[fid],0))
        else:
            lengths = nx.single_source_dijkstra_path_length(G, fid,101)
            nCur = len(lengths)-1
            for i in lengths:
                if nDict[i]==0:
                    nCur-=1
            cursor.updateRow((fid,nDict[fid],nCur))
```

Comment: Looks interesting, are you able to share the code you used so I can verify on my end.

Comment: I'm marking the as the answer has it solved my question and also help me refine my / rule set, thanks.